# Variable not initialized (Beginner)

Tags: variables, initialization

NetBeans tells me that "index may have not been initialized" in the while loop and that "index has not been used" when I define it!

```
public class ClassBenchmark {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endtime = startime + 60000;
        long index;

        while (startime>endtime) {
            index++;    
        }

        System.out.print(index);
    }
}
```

I am making a simple benchmark.

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definition is not the same as initialization. You have indeed defined it, but have not given it a value. Just put:

```
long index = 0;
```

The error will vanish.

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize the index variable like this

```
long index = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess stuff makes sense after all.